# How to solve Unity compiling problems?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game on Unity, but i am currently stuck because of two compiler errors:

- CS1002;
- CS1003;
  My C# Script does not have any compiler errors, no semicolon or coma lacking, but in Unity it gives me those two errors.

I tried to get Input Text set to decimal numbers on Unity from 3 Input Fields.

On the C# Script I gave those Input Fields a GameObject so they could use the functions bellow.
Because I needed it to make a number comparison with an 'If(VariableName >= DecimalNumber){}' so I changed the GameObject to a float, using 'float VariableName.GetComponent<InputField>().text;'.

Unity compiler says that 3 semicolons and 3 commas are missing on the script.
I verified it twice and did not saw any of those missing. I need help to solve this.

This is the code from the C# Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbeCj.png)
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class HOMEMADE : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject CreateNewDesignMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject LoadDesignMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject CreateNew3DModelMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Load3DModelMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject OptionsMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ContinueCreateNewDesignMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ErrorMessageCNDM;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject InicialWidth;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject InicialHeight;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject SeelingHeight;

    public void Start()
    {
        CreateNewDesignMenu.SetActive(false);
        LoadDesignMenu.SetActive(false);
        CreateNew3DModelMenu.SetActive(false);
        Load3DModelMenu.SetActive(false);
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(false);
        ContinueCreateNewDesignMenu.SetActive(false);
        ErrorMessageCNDM.SetActive(false);
    }


    // 1.- Create New Design
    public void CreateNewDesign()
    {
        CreateNewDesignMenu.SetActive(true); //open CreateNewDesign Menu
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(false); //close Options Menu
    }

    public void CloseCreateNewDesign()
    {
        CreateNewDesignMenu.SetActive(false); //close CreateNewDesign Menu
    }


    public void GetInputs()
    {
        float InicialWidth.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        float InicialHeight.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        float SeelingHeight.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
    }
    public void ContinueCreateNewDesign()
    {
        if (InicialWidth >= 5.00 && InicialHeight >= 5.00 && SeelingHeight >= 5.00 && InicialWidth <= 20.0 && InicialHeight <= 20.0 && SeelingHeight <= 20.0)
        {
            ContinueCreateNewDesignMenu.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessageCNDM.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void CloseContinueCreateNewDesign()
    {
        ContinueCreateNewDesignMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void CloseErrorMessageCNDM()
    {
        ErrorMessageCNDM.SetActive(false);
    }

    // 2.- Load Design
    public void LoadDesign()
    {
        LoadDesignMenu.SetActive(true);
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void CloseLoadDesign()
    {
        LoadDesignMenu.SetActive(false);
    }



    // 3.- Create New 3D Model
    public void CreateNew3DModel()
    {
        CreateNew3DModelMenu.SetActive(true);
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void CloseCreateNew3DModel()
    {
        CreateNew3DModelMenu.SetActive(false);
    }



    // 4.- Load 3D Model
    public void Load3DModel()
    {
        Load3DModelMenu.SetActive(true);
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void CloseLoad3DModel()
    {
        Load3DModelMenu.SetActive(false);
    }



    // 5.- Options
    public void Options()
    {
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void CloseOptions()
    {
        OptionsMenu.SetActive(false);
    }



    // 6.- Quit Game
    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("THE GAME WAS CLOSED");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally when you see a slew of "missing semicolon" errors but your code seems to have enough of them, it means the compiler is confused by your code elsewhere. In this case, take a look at your logic for `GetInputs()`. The code in there is a cross between an assignment and a declaration, but in its present state it doesn't make sense. Tidy that up and store those `.text` properties in class-level float variables. Also, your logic for `ContinueCreateNewDesign()` is also invalid - you're comparing `GameObject` values against float values, so determine what you actually want to compare there.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the variable a name. A float declaration should be in the shape of `float variable = value;`, not `float value;`. Also, when converting a string to a float, use [`Single.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Single_Parse_System_String_):

```
public void GetInputs()
{
    float InitialWidth = float.Parse(InicialWidth.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
    float InitialHeight = float.Parse(InicialHeight.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
    float CeilingHeight = float.Parse(SeelingHeight.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it really seems that I was not paying attention. I'm new to C# coding so I do a lot of errors while coding. And I saw that you corrected my english too, thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Also the corrected spelling was also to not shadow the object's variable :)

Comment: Yes, I understood that :)